# Moving to another storyboard inside closure

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

```
api.postUserLogin(Parameters: params) { (json) in
            print(json)

            if (json["status"].string == "true") {
                self.user.id = json["data"]["id"].string
                self.user.verify_status = json["data"]["verify_status"].string

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as UIViewController
                present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please give some context, what is the result, what you expect?

Comment: I just need to go to another view that is in another storyboard. But a problem occurs in the "present" statement

Comment: Note that the json variable comes from a closure and is working well.

Comment: I think you should not do present here, just give use the callback here, and in callback present your new vc and please tell what is the problem in the present

Comment: @Creign What is the issue, Are you not able to present the MainViewController?

Comment: @ImadAli yes. that is exactly my problem :(

Comment: @ImadAli If I do that, the code will not consider the api request result that comes from a closure

Comment: @ImadAli I am not familiar with DispatchQueue. Can you please make me a sample for my code?

Comment: @ImadAli I've tried putting it inside the if statement but it doesn't move to another view.

Comment: @Creign Then you need to provide more information. Code and problem, Edit your question.

Comment: @Creign you need to pass information from api to `MainViewController`? is that what you trying?

Comment: You probably need to dispatch to the main thread.

Comment: @Creign Can u provide more details, Moving to Another Storyboard in closure or function is not big deal. Can u try that code in Dispatch Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
func callViewController(){
    let viewController: UIViewController =  UIStoryboard(name:"STORYBOARD_NAME",bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
    let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    window.rootViewController = viewController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```